# How can I identify Facebook users that don't use my app yet?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm developing an app in which users log with their Facebook account, but only the Facebook profiles that the system administrator have previously entered.

In other words, the system admin enters a bunch of Facebook profiles, and when the user tries to log into my app, the system checks if there's a record for that Facebook profile.

I used to do this using the user's Facebook username, because the admin could get that information easily from a Facebook profile's URL, and Facebook provided that username when the user logged in. This is not possible anymore with Graph API 2.0, because Facebook does not provide the username field anymore.

So do you guys have any suggestion on how the system administrator could easily identify users, so they would be granted access in my app?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use email

Comment: @WizKid but do you know any easy way to obtain the user's email? Like, is it shown somewhere, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

@WizKid is right, using the user's email is the best way to do this. Any user will be able to login, but then you can build in a check to see if that user's email is in your "pre-approved" list.

To get the user's email address, you need to ask them for it in the login dialog using the `scope` parameter. In the JS SDK, it looks like this:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
  // handle response

}, { scope: "email" }); // <<< the important bit
```

**Note:** with the new Graph 2.0 Login dialog, a user can choose not to provide their email address by unchecking it in the "edit the info you provide" section of the dialog. As a result you'll need to double check that the user actually provided their email address.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I get that I can use the email when the user tries to log in, but how could the system administrator find this in someone's Facebook profile? I mean, in my situation, the admin needs to enter this prior to the user trying to log in (so the system can check it when he logs in via Facebook login dialog).